# Rotation of a rectangle in 3D

Tags: python

I have 4 xyz locations for the four corners of a square. The square does not deform. How would I use the displacement of the four corners to calculate the rotation of the square in each axis?

Thanks

I am not sure where to begin.

Comment: you'd be easier starting with pen and pencil, and geometry text book, maybe. Once you get the formula, them putting a program to getting you numbers is trivial - like 2 lines of code.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.